# Extract fixed position values in nested dictionary Python

Tags: python, dictionary

```py
d = {'k1':{'inside1':[1,'one']},
     'k2':{'inside2':[2,'two']},
     'k3':{'inside3':[3,'three']}}
```

possible to get the expected result of 6 (1+2+3) using for loop?

Comment: 5 != 1 + 2 + 3, do you mean 6?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```py
sum((v2[0] for v in d.values() for v2 in v.values()))
6
```

Comment: You can remove second parentheses pair for readability, generator inside a function call can be implicit.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = sum([sum([lst[0] for lst in dic.values()]) for dic in d.values()])
```